# options_from_collection_for_select in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm building a simple form to let users of my rails 4 site message each other.

In the form, the user can select the recipient of the message with a select list of all the users in the system (it's a small user base).

Right now the form control looks like this, and works fine:

```
<%= f.select(:to_id, options_from_collection_for_select(User.all, :id, :first_name), {}, {:class => 'form-control'}) %>
```

However, there's a "nickname" field in the `Users` table as well-- I'd like to have the form show the nickname (if it exists) as well as the user's first / last name-- so the value of the select would be:

```
<option>Snoop Dogg - Calvin Broadus</option>
```

rather than just

```
<option>Calvin</option>
```

Is this possible?

Comment: why can't you define a method on User and reference that method (instead of :first_name) in your options_from_collection_for_select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a `display_name` on the `Users` model

```
def display_name
  nickname || first_name
end
```

Then update your form to reference it

```
<%= f.select(:to_id, options_from_collection_for_select(User.all, :id, :display_name), {}, {:class => 'form-control'}) %>
```